# How can I get a Windows binary without dependencies from a Python application with a GUI?

Tags: python, windows, gtk

I am a Python developer using a Linux (Ubuntu) system for development. I want to write GUI application for Windows users. Those users are not developers, so I want to make the installation / execution as simple as possible.

Currently, it seems to me that I need the user to install GTK / Qt and then use `pip` to install my application. This seems much too complicated.

Is there a way to get a Windows binary without dependencies which simply starts the GTK3 application? (currently, my code is relatively straight-forward, see http://pastebin.com/rNcFm1m7 if you're interested).

### What I've tried

#### pyinstaller

I tried to use pyinstaller. I ran the following command on my Linux machine with [this code](http://pastebin.com/rNcFm1m7) saved as `formula_writer.py`.

```
pyinstaller --onefile formula_writer.py; dist/formula_writer
```

It didn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/moose/FormulaWriter/build/formula_writer/out00-PYZ.pyz/gi", line 42, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name _gi
```

As GTK3 might be the problem, I wrote a very simple Python GUI application with GTK2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# example base.py
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk


class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)
        self.window.show()

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()
print(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

It still doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/moose/FormulaWriter/build/formula_writer_gtk2/out00-PYZ.pyz/gtk", line 30, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/moose/FormulaWriter/build/formula_writer_gtk2/out00-PYZ.pyz/gobject", line 26, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/moose/FormulaWriter/build/formula_writer_gtk2/out00-PYZ.pyz/glib", line 22, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _glib
```

Comment: you need a windows box .... and you need to build your package with something like pyinstaller

Comment: `python my_script.py` works on Linux, but I cannot execute the binary on Linux. I didn't try if it works on Windows.

So I guess GTK3 is not supported by pyinstaller. Ok. But GTK2 seems not to work, too (see updated question).

Comment: first make sure you can run it with `python my_script.py` on the windows machine ... anyway im installing gtk now ... ill let you know soonish ... why are you still doing linux stuff? this question is about windows i thought? I have no idea how well pyinstaller works for linux ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, this question is about Windows. But I only have a Linux machine at home. If I want to test something for windows, I have to go to university. I thought if it doesn't work with Linux, it is unlikely to work with windows. I'll try it with Windows tomorrow. (Thank you for helping me!)

Comment: sure it worked fine for me ... first i ensured that I could run your second example with just `python script.py` ... then I built it `C:\pyinstaller\pyinstaller.py --onefile script.py` ... here is a link to the resulting exe https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18004504/gtk5.exe

Comment: Nice. I've just found https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-windows-installers looks promising which also requires a Windows computer. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: ok or do that ... I can guarantee you distutils is almost certainly much more complicated ... it was very easy for me to build your example with pyinstaller ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a Windows computer. There is no way around.

However, on a Windows machine there are multiple, simple options:

- [`pyinstaller`](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki): Tried, works
- [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/): I didn't try it so far

If you have a Python package, you can also go for

- `python setup.py bdist --formats=wininst`: Works, creates an installer
- `python setup.py bdist --formats=msi`: Works, also creates an installer